# Uncaught ReferenceError: gsap is not defined

Tags: javascript, html, css

I can't figure out why this won't work, I'm getting the error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: gsap is not defined
> initialAnimation        script.js:22
> Async call from setTimeout
> increaseCounter         script.js:77
> (anonymous function)    script.js:81
> (anonymous function)    script.js:80
> (anonymous function)    script.js:86#

## test.html

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<svg class="defs">
  <defs>
    <path
      id="Line"
      d="M20.039,27.377,5.026,73.556,30.041,20.27,13.222,76.345,41.164,17.978,20.039,81.263,45.772,23.144l-14,53.2L53.453,17.978,37.507,81.263,61.2,23.144,47.811,81.263,71.625,20.27,56.884,81.263l20.907-55.5L65.719,82.8,85.634,20.27,77.792,84.616,94.938,17.978l-9.3,69.346,20.875-69.346L99.453,87.324l16.588-64.18-6.134,64.18L126.219,25.76,120.97,84.616l13.18-57.24-4.656,57.24,15.818-55.643L141.475,82.8l11.988-59.651V82.8l10.827-64.817-1.653,66.638,11.145-57.24-2.854,57.24,13.789-61.472L179.508,78.2l17.746-60.225L183.233,87.324l24.209-71.9L197.254,82.8l19.28-67.376-12.477,69.2,23.034-69.2-10.557,71.9L234.78,20.27l-7.689,67.054,16-64.18-2.082,64.18L253.012,20.27"
      transform="translate(-2.173 -14.462)"
      fill="none"
      stroke="var(--color-primary)"
      stroke-width="6"
    />
  </defs>
</svg>
<div class="cursor"></div>
<div class="loading">Loading...</div>
<nav class="menu">
  <svg
    class="papers"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    width="533.266"
    height="737.909"
    viewBox="0 0 533.266 737.909"
  >
    <clipPath id="PaperPath-1">
      <path
        id="Path_1"
        data-name="Path 1"
        d="M609.963,1.316s1.631,119.672,0,118.47,10.55-1.059,10.55-1.059l9.232,2.043,8.724-4.821,10-4.51h3.42l4.2-5.02,6.206-1.635,4.255-5.49,4.827-4.471s22.139-61.3,47.258-69.16c.781-.244,1.525-.495,2.5-.848,20.5-7.416,13.358-22.092,8.182-23.5-.336,0-7.568-1.77-8.182-1.666C709.438-2.843,609.963,1.316,609.963,1.316Z"
        transform="translate(-608)"
        fill="none"
        stroke="#707070"
        stroke-width="1"
      />
    </clipPath>
    <clipPath id="PaperPath-2">
      <path
        id="Path_2"
        data-name="Path 2"
        d="M617,117.02s-10.234,111.55-8.467,112.057S607.3,345.01,611.517,347.323s16.414-3.365,16.414-3.365l4.984,2.2L635,340.946h7.213l4.245-5.583,6.625-1.523,5.391-8.624,9.734-10.208,2.5,2.92,4.906-13.4,7.768-3.154,3.511-6.55,8.565-2.351,6.533-9.991,11.208-1.538,5.428-10.663,7.917-1.362-1.13-6.479,10.96-4.059v-4.963l10.257-1.357,6.021-6.366,6.393-1.089,7.468-7.5,8.273-3.178,8.957,3.178h9.826l2.237,3.826h12.654l6.6-3.826,8.028,3.826,7.815-3.826,8.363-3.178,3.646-4.843h10.812l5.389-2.72h5.1l16.791-13.132,8.518-4.181,6.672-5.068,8.586-2.091,2.125-3.778h5.532l10.921-6.8H939.5v6.8h7.848l2.949,3.778,6.412-3.778,6.031,5.869,8.511-3.8,3.06,3.8h12.115l3.789,7.112,15.8-2.045,6.569-3.022,5.564,3.022,7.816-3.022,3.819,3.022,11.422-5.068,6.032,2.045,12.643-2.045h5.73l4.485-2.091,11.469,2.091,5.662-2.091,7.918,4.136,8.6-2.045,5.894,5.068,4.711-3.022,4.506,3.022,3.286-3.022,8.28,3.022,4.158-2.114,7.015-204.521s-153.329,2.213-155.17,0S730.774-.11,730.774-.11l-8.383,16.784h-9.2v8.534H701.986v5.887h-15.1l3.123,18.758L668.2,47.205l2.5,9.348h-4.914v6.9H655.633v8.057l-9.18,6.756-4.245,5.329v3.976L635,90.185v5.554l-2.081,5.6H627.93l-2.559,8.186Z"
        transform="translate(-608)"
        fill="none"
        stroke="#707070"
        stroke-width="1"
      />
    </clipPath>
    <clipPath id="PaperPath-3">
      <path
        id="Path_3"
        data-name="Path 3"
        d="M610,343l8.076-2.827H624.7L627.716,343l5.668-7.019h5.261l5.425-3.94h5.294v-4.317h6.862l6.408-6.891H667.8V309.617l6.7-2.224,8.05-6.3,5.568-10.577,12.094-5.055,5.575-8.477s42.061-37.319,46.861-37.722,24.872-13.385,24.872-13.385l7.48,1.493,6.56,4.326,6.969,7.566,12.051-4.724h7.2l7.453-2.841h5.154l7.378-5.819h7l24.308-5.925,10.862-11.705,11.043-3.836,7.811-5.848h7.434l16.763-10.686,8.982,3.978,4.826-3.978,9.648,5.931h24.047l4.968,7.154h6.119l8.071,2.111h7.2l7.762,1.338,7.1-1.338,9.726,1.338,11.139-3.45,9.979,2.111,4.9-2.111h15.588l10.083-2.4,10.176,4.51,13.264,1.338,7.179-1.338,14.668,1.338h16.193l4.534,277.942-22.531-1.829-9.98,3.788-8.315-17.751-15.012,4.3h-6.276l-5.946-2.638-8.037,5.213h-9.05l-6.538,7.083h-6.045l-3.474,5.54-8.953-7.626h-8.68l-11.991,5.874H993.325l-10.266,13.273-17.437,3.8-8.15-5.684-2.289,5.684-11.985-3.8v3.8l-11.224-3.8-5.774,3.8-4.687-3.8-4.905,1.486h-8.354l-2.023,2.319-4.618-2.319H887.994l-8.053,5.411-10.862-5.411-6.733,2.319-7.854-2.319-4.827-5.594-4.894,2.229-10.984-2.229-3.4-4.288-10.271-6.836-5.136,3.711-2.64-5.54-8.3,1.829-12.488-5.7L781.634,464.8l-7.327-1.349-21.658-17.214-10.956-3.406-8.188-7.083L719.077,426.4h-13.29l-11.444-8.317L682.551,411.3H674.5l-6.7-6.495-8.975-6.149-9.458,2.825-5.294-2.825-5.425,2.825-8.13-5.085-5.811,2.259-12.823,2.825Z"
        transform="translate(-608)"
        fill="none"
        stroke="#707070"
        stroke-width="1"
      />
    </clipPath>
    <clipPath id="PaperPath-4">
      <path
        id="Path_5"
        data-name="Path 5"
        d="M612.025,381.038l.35,356.761s245.421-8.286,250.815-7.131,9.442-2.9,9.442-2.9l6.762,2.9L897,737.8l12.463-7.131s226.949,2.583,228.153,0,0-119.231,0-119.231-51.707-20.856-94.377-49.928-76.3-66.361-76.3-66.361-110.493-1.722-110.2-8.407-13.519-9.089-13.519-9.089l-14.7,5.228-10.219-13.122-9.864,7.894-22.16-18.821-7.52,3.32-16.405-13.185L742.451,429.2l-10.641,3.85-15.087-13.324Z"
        transform="translate(-608)"
        fill="none"
        stroke="#707070"
        stroke-width="1"
      />
    </clipPath>
    <clipPath id="PaperPath-5">
      <path
        id="Path_6"
        data-name="Path 6"
        d="M1139.139,483.046c.255,3.979,0,128.624,0,128.624l-26.07-3.752-6-9.613-19.113,4.743V593.82l-6.342-5.307-4.052,5.307-3.87-5.307-10.323-7.346-2.42,7.346-4.462-15.124-13.649-4.933-6.073-9.783H1025.5l-10.351-9.843-7.414-11.553H997.052l-5.165-13.656-9.249-4-12.925-10.481-10.5-6.209V488.687l15.2,3.325,8.219-8.966h9.249l5.165-9.115h18.1l6.952-6.121,7.326,6.121,27.056-8.623h12.864l8.212-5.567,10.393,8.068,13.616-2.5S1138.884,479.067,1139.139,483.046Z"
        transform="translate(-608)"
        fill="none"
        stroke="#707070"
        stroke-width="1"
      />
    </clipPath>

    <foreignObject
      class="image-2"
      width="100%"
      height="100%"
      clip-path="url(#PaperPath-2)"
    >
      <div class="imageSlider">
        <img
          class="imageSlider__slide"
          width="100%"
          src="https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/20098648/72714431-f1b2c180-3b83-11ea-851b-276f4fec08af.png"
        />
        <img
          class="imageSlider__slide -next"
          width="100%"
          src="https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/20098648/72714507-0abb7280-3b84-11ea-86fd-2f94db92df09.png"
        />
      </div>
    </foreignObject>

    <foreignObject
      class="image-1"
      width="100%"
      height="100%"
      clip-path="url(#PaperPath-1)"
    >
      <div class="imageSlider">
        <img
          class="imageSlider__slide"
          width="100%"
          src="https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/20098648/72714318-c334e680-3b83-11ea-8120-50044cc21cde.png"
        />
        <img
          class="imageSlider__slide -next"
          width="100%"
          src="https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/20098648/72714389-e3fd3c00-3b83-11ea-83b9-50b6e3959172.png"
        />
      </div>
    </foreignObject>

    <foreignObject
      class="image-3"
      width="100%"
      height="100%"
      clip-path="url(#PaperPath-3)"
    >
      <div class="imageSlider">
        <img
          class="imageSlider__slide"
          width="100%"
          src="https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/20098648/72714549-23c42380-3b84-11ea-9dff-e2c4da0e7d7a.png"
        />
        <img
          class="imageSlider__slide -next"
          width="100%"
          src="https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/20098648/72714577-2fafe580-3b84-11ea-997a-68cbb43a1f77.png"
        />
      </div>
    </foreignObject>

    <foreignObject
      class="image-4"
      width="100%"
      height="100%"
      clip-path="url(#PaperPath-4)"
    >
      <div class="imageSlider">
        <img
          class="imageSlider__slide"
          width="100%"
          src="https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/20098648/72714732-756cae00-3b84-11ea-8b8f-186f383f72e2.png"
        />
        <img
          class="imageSlider__slide -next"
          width="100%"
          src="https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/20098648/72716269-2bd19280-3b87-11ea-980a-b77ef072b476.png"
        />
      </div>
    </foreignObject>

    <foreignObject
      class="image-5"
      width="100%"
      height="100%"
      clip-path="url(#PaperPath-5)"
    >
      <div class="imageSlider">
        <img
          class="imageSlider__slide"
          width="100%"
          src="https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/20098648/72714844-abaa2d80-3b84-11ea-8f83-4ead06a2a6ca.png"
        />
        <img
          class="imageSlider__slide -next"
          width="100%"
          src="https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/20098648/72714802-9208e600-3b84-11ea-951a-f0267b4d7a5d.png"
        />
      </div>
    </foreignObject>
  </svg>
  <div class="menuList">
    <a
      href="https://twitter.com/kiarash_zar"
      target="_blank"
      class="menuListItem"
    >
      Home
      <span class="menuListItem__text -hover">Home</span>
      <span class="menuListItem__text -initial">Home</span>
      <svg
        class="menuListItem__line"
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
        width="100%"
        height="100%"
        viewBox="0 0 250 81.455"
      >
        <use xlink:href="#Line"></use>
      </svg>
    </a>
    <a
      href="https://twitter.com/kiarash_zar"
      target="_blank"
      class="menuListItem"
    >
      About
      <span class="menuListItem__text -hover">About</span>
      <span class="menuListItem__text -initial">About</span>
      <svg
        class="menuListItem__line"
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
        width="100%"
        height="100%"
        viewBox="0 0 250 81.455"
      >
        <use xlink:href="#Line"></use>
      </svg>
    </a>
    <a
      href="https://twitter.com/kiarash_zar"
      target="_blank"
      class="menuListItem"
    >
      Contact
      <span class="menuListItem__text -hover">Contact</span>
      <span class="menuListItem__text -initial">Contact</span>
      <svg
        class="menuListItem__line"
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
        width="100%"
        height="100%"
        viewBox="0 0 250 81.455"
      >
        <use xlink:href="#Line"></use>
      </svg>
    </a>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </div>
</nav>
```

## style.css

```
    *, *::before, *::after {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html{
  --color-primary: #dddad2;
  font-size: 62.5%;
}

html, body {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

body {
  background-color: var(--color-primary);
  position: relative;
  font-family: 'Ibarra Real Nova', serif;
  user-select: none;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.defs {
  display: none;
}

.loading {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: var(--color-primary);
  z-index: 2;
  font-size: 4rem;
}

.cursor {
  position: absolute;
  left: -4rem;
  top: -4rem;
  width: 4rem;
  height: 4rem;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  border-radius: 50%;
  transition: 0.2s ease-out;
  z-index: 100;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.menu {
  height: 70vh;
  width: 35vw;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
}

.menuListItem {
  overflow: hidden;
  font-size: 9rem;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: transparent;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.menuListItem:not(:last-child) {
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.menuListItem__text {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.menuListItem__text.-hover {
  color: #000;
  bottom: 100%;
}

.menuListItem__text.-initial {
  color: #fff;
  top: 100%;
}

.menuListItem__line {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 0.5rem;
  stroke-dasharray: 3400;
  stroke-dashoffset: 3400;
}

.papers {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  z-index: -2;
  overflow: visible;
}


.image-1 {
  transform: translate(-15%, -25rem) rotate(-15deg);
}

.image-2 {
  transform: translate(-10%, calc(-50% - 10rem)) rotate(-15deg);
}

.image-3 {
  transform: translate(100%, calc(70% + 10rem)) rotate(15deg);
}

.image-4 {
  transform: translate(10%, 65%) rotate(5deg);
}

.image-5 {
  transform: translate(25%, 45%) rotate(15deg);
}

.imageSlider {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.imageSlider__slide.-next {
  transform: translateX(-100%);
}

.imageSlider__slide {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

/* Chrome bug in backface-visibility */

@media (max-width: 1400px) {
  .menu {
    transform: scale(0.81);
  }
}

@media (min-aspect-ratio: 5/2) {
  .menu {
    transform: scale(0.7);
  }
}

@media (min-aspect-ratio: 6/2) {
  .menu {
    transform: scale(0.58);
  }
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .menu {
    transform: scale(0.55);
  }
}
```

## script.js

```
    // Go full page view for best results!

const cursor = document.querySelector('.cursor');
const menuItems = document.querySelectorAll('.menuListItem');
const menuItemTexts = document.querySelectorAll('.menuListItem__text.-initial');
const imageSliders = document.querySelectorAll('.imageSlider');
const image1 = document.querySelector('.image-1');
const image2 = document.querySelector('.image-2');
const image3 = document.querySelector('.image-3');
const image4 = document.querySelector('.image-4');
const image5 = document.querySelector('.image-5');
const loading = document.querySelector('.loading');

const moveCursor = ({ clientX, clientY }) => {
  const x = clientX + cursor.clientWidth / 2;
  const y = clientY + cursor.clientHeight / 2;

  cursor.style.transform = `translate(${x}px, ${y}px)`;
};

const initialAnimation = () => {
  gsap.to(menuItemTexts, 0.5, {
    yPercent: -100,
    delay: 0.4
  });

  gsap.to(image1, 0.9, {
    y: 0,
    x: 0,
    rotate: 0,
    ease: 'power3.out',
    delay: 0.1
  });

  gsap.to(image2, 1.2, {
    y: 0,
    x: 0,
    rotate: 0,
    ease: 'power3.out'
  });

  gsap.to(image3, 1.2, {
    y: 0,
    x: 0,
    rotate: 0,
    ease: 'power3.out'
  });

  gsap.to(image4, 1.2, {
    y: 0,
    x: 0,
    rotate: 0,
    ease: 'power3.out',
    delay: 0.2
  });

  gsap.to(image5, 1.2, {
    y: 0,
    x: 0,
    rotate: 0,
    ease: 'power3.out',
    delay: 0.2,
    onComplete: () => {
      Array.from(imageSliders).forEach(imageSliderItem => {
        imageSliderItem.style.backfaceVisibility = 'hidden';
      });
    }
  });
};

const loadImages = (() => {
  let loadedImagesCount = 0;
  const increaseCounter = () => {
    loadedImagesCount++;
    if (loadedImagesCount === document.images.length) {
      loading.style.display = 'none';
      setTimeout(initialAnimation, 500);
    }
  };
  Array.from(document.images).forEach(imageElement => {
    if (imageElement.complete) increaseCounter();
    else {
      imageElement.addEventListener('load', increaseCounter, false);
    }
  });
})();

const scaleRotate = (target, { shouldReverse, delay }) => {
  const activeSlide = target.querySelector('.imageSlider__slide:not(.-next)');
  const scale = shouldReverse ? 1 : 1.1;
  const rotate = shouldReverse ? 0 : 7;

  gsap.to(activeSlide, 0.9, {
    scale,
    rotate,
    delay,
    ease: 'power2.Out'
  });
};

const slide = (target, { shouldReverse, delay = 0, extraDuration = 0 }) => {
  const activeSlide = target.querySelector('.imageSlider__slide:not(.-next)');
  const nextSlide = target.querySelector('.imageSlider__slide.-next');
  const xPercent = shouldReverse ? 0 : 100;

  gsap.to([activeSlide, nextSlide], 0.7 + extraDuration, {
    xPercent,
    delay,
    ease: 'power2.inOut'
  });
};

const toggleAnimation = ({ currentTarget, type }, index) => {
  const initialText = currentTarget.querySelector(
    '.menuListItem__text.-initial'
  );
  const hoverText = currentTarget.querySelector('.menuListItem__text.-hover');
  const strokeLine = currentTarget.querySelector('.menuListItem__line');
  const shouldReverse = type === 'mouseout';
  const y = !shouldReverse ? 0 : -100;
  const ease = !shouldReverse ? 'power2.out' : 'power2.in';
  const strokeDashoffset = !shouldReverse ? 0 : 3400;

  gsap.to(initialText, 0.4, { yPercent: 0 + y, ease });
  gsap.to(hoverText, 0.4, { yPercent: 100 + y, ease });
  gsap.to(strokeLine, 0.5, { strokeDashoffset, ease: 'power2.in' });

  switch (index) {
    case 0:
      slide(image5, { shouldReverse, delay: 0.025, extraDuration: 0.3 });
      slide(image2, { shouldReverse, delay: 0.05 });
      scaleRotate(image3, { shouldReverse, delay: 0.1 });
      slide(image4, { shouldReverse, delay: 0.15 });
      break;

    case 1:
      slide(image1, { shouldReverse, delay: 0.025, extraDuration: 0.3 });
      slide(image3, { shouldReverse, delay: 0.05 });
      scaleRotate(image2, { shouldReverse, delay: 0.1 });
      scaleRotate(image4, { shouldReverse, delay: 0.1 });
      break;

    case 2:
      slide(image1, { shouldReverse, delay: 0.025, extraDuration: 0.3 });
      slide(image4, { shouldReverse, delay: 0.05 });
      scaleRotate(image3, { shouldReverse, delay: 0.1 });
      slide(image5, { shouldReverse, delay: 0.1 });
      break;
  }
};

window.addEventListener('mousemove', moveCursor);

Array.from(menuItems).forEach((item, index) => {
  const handleEvent = e => toggleAnimation(e, index);
  item.addEventListener('mouseover', handleEvent);
  item.addEventListener('mouseout', handleEvent);
});
```

Answer (score 4):

You don't appear to be actually loading the gsap code before trying to use it?

In your **test.html** file, you need to add a reference to the GSAP.js code:

```
<script src="/[YOUR_DIRECTORY]/gsap.min.js"></script>
```

**Please see (for more info):**

https://greensock.com/docs/v3/Installation

**They also seem to offer a configuration helper:**

https://greensock.com/docs/v3/Installation#CDN

If you use the configuration helper, it should make it much more clear what you need to do.

**Example Script Tag:**

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.0.5/gsap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: That's brill, thank you so much! Much appriciated(:

Comment: I'm getting the error :Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) now though? once installing gsap and adding the line you've said and also -> <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.0.5/gsap.min.js"></script>

Comment: Hey, I've added an example script tag to the answer. You're missing https:// for starters :) - Try my example and let me know how you get on.

Comment: Hi, its working but when debugging it in webstorm I'm getting the error: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)